# Win 10 - MIT AppInventor emulator.exe has stopped working

Tags: windows, android-emulator, compatibility

I've been successfully teaching MIT AppInventor emulator at my school on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 for the past two years. We have upgraded to Windows 10, and it stopped working.

More stressful is, that I tried to use the emulator on my private home PC (Windows 10) and it doesn't work, too. Meaning, even on a fresh Windows 10 update I can't get it to work. Let alone the school computers.

[image]

Please let me know, if the MIT AppInventor emulator should work on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried going through the "compatibility mode" options in the emulator.exe properties dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to reboot the windows 10 machine. Then go to the App Inventor menu and "Hard reset" the connection. This way, a new update of the AI2 companion is installed inside the emulator. It worked. All good now.